# From list column in pandas, access each string in list to remove the numbers and periods

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column having list of strings in each rows. But each string have numbers and periods which i have to remove. I'm unable to access the strings of the list in each row, here's the sample dataframe:

```
df['column_name']
output:
['1.one','2.two','3. three','4.four ']
['1.one','2.two','3. three','4.four ','5.five']
['1.one','2.two','3. three']
...
```

I tried as below, and my output is:

```
df4['column_name'].str[0].str.replace('\d+\.','')
output:
one
one
one
...
```

but i need an output like this:

```
df4['column_name'].str[0].str.replace('\d+\.','')
output:
'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'
```

likewise i have to loop over all the rows of the dataframe, :(. Any help would be very much appreciated !!!

Comment: you can either iterate each row and replace the elements in the list or do something like `df['column_name'].str.join('').str.replace('\d+\.',',').str.lstrip(",")` if you want a joined list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, to get the column of type string:

```
df['column_name'].str.join(',').str.replace('\d+\.|[ ]','').str.replace(',',', ')
```

Or this to get the column of type list:

```
df['column_name'].str.join(',').str.replace('\d+\.|[ ]','').str.split(',')
```

---

Output:

```
#first solution:
0          one, two, three, four
1    one, two, three, four, five
2                one, two, three
Name: column_name, dtype: object

#second solution:

0          [one, two, three, four]
1    [one, two, three, four, five]
2                [one, two, three]
Name: column_name, dtype: object
```